# Blend for Visual Studio 2012 design view not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, design-view, blend-2012

I'm working on a Windows Store App in Visual Studio 2012 and decided it might be easier to start using blend for the interface and layout. But in my attempts to make this layout design easier for myself, I have run into a problem with the design view. The error message is that design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM platforms. 
I'm familiar with this error from Visual Studio but I was just wondering if there's a simple way to change the target platforms so I can see the design view in Blend?

I know there have been problems with blend for VS 2012 up until now, but I thought maybe this was an easy one to fix that I'm missing somewhere.

If anyone knows a way to fix this I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

1. Close Blend
2. Open the project in Visual Studio 2012
3. Change `Release/Debug Configuration` to `Any CPU` or `x86`
4. **Save All in Visual Studio** to make sure it saves the project 
   (The Project does not save when you run!)
5. Reopen the document in Blend

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Build->Configuration Manager and change the Platform to 'Any CPU'.

Additionally you can enable the 'Solution Platform' dropdown in the toolbar by clicking the little down arrow right to the debugging Toolbar items then click 'Add remove buttons' and select 'Solution Platforms'.

Comment: Oh yeah I can change it in VS no problem, but when I try to open it with Blend it still comes up with that message. It's like it doesn't recognize the change made in VS. Any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your question. I thought you were talking about the blend functionality integrated in VS2012 and not the external Blend tool. Unfortunately I have no ideas why this is happening in the external Blend tool.

Answer (score 1):

Change .NetFramework from 4.5 to 4.0

Comment: This solution helped me when I had initially created a project in Blend 2015 RC with .Net 4.5.2 and then opened in Blend 2013. I couldn't find feedback anywhere that it doesn't support it but changing the project type to .Net 4.5.1 solved my issues. (Although this is unrelated to the Arm/x64 issue of the original question)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install windows phone sdk for blend to work correctly in your application.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471